# Navigation using Term Store in my enterprise Wiki Site is not working well

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, wiki, term

My problem is as follows:-

1. I have a site collection that contain an Enterprise Wiki template.
2. I create a new Term Store
3. I link the term store to the “Wiki Category” column.
4. When I add or edit a Wiki page I can select a term from the term store without any problem.
5. If I click on the added term which is associated with a Wiki article , then all the related wikis which has this term will be listed.
6. Then I have added a left and upper Navigation to the enterprise Wiki also using the same Term Store.
7. But **the problem I'm facing**, is that if I click on a term in the navigation the following error will be shown:-

> The page you're looking for doesn't exist.
>   Check for a typo in the URL, or go to the site home

While I was expecting to list all the Wikis pages that are related to this term?

Can anyone advice of what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Not Supported.

You can only use a Term Store for EITHER tagging OR navigation. Not both at the same time.

(note - when you use it for navigation it works in a very different way to a taxonomy store for tagging).

Answer (score 0):

The default settings for navigation using metadata tags is to create a "friendly url" that one will be directed to when you click on the tag from the navigation bar. But because the page is not created yet, the site will show the "page does not exist" template.

To display pages that are associated to the term is something I am trying to figure out too, unfortunately.

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer, as this answer http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69122/managed-navigation-using-a-managed-metadata-term-set-is-not-working-well-in-an-e/187400#187400. Try to be more specific, or if the questions are the same, one of them should be closed as a duplicate.