# Managed Navigation using a Managed Metadata term set is not working well in an Enterprise wiki site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, managed-metadata, term-store

I have an Enterprise Wiki subsite and I have defined a site Navigation for this sub site to be of type “Managed Navigation using a Managed Metadata term set”.
But currently I am facing these critical issues regarding the left side sub site navigation:-

1. I have created the Term store by the site collection administration, but the site navigation which is based on the managed term store does not show up for the contributors or reader users , it shows up only for the Site Collection admin.

[image]

[image]

2. I have linked the Wiki pages categories column to use the same managed term store, but if the site administrator clicks on a term in the navigation then the following  error will be displayed instead of displaying all the pages that are associated with the term.

[image]

Can anyone advice on what is causing these problems?
BR

Answer (score 0):

You might want to inherit permissions from the parent site's hidden list taxonomy

Comment: Please extend this answer with some steps to take to accomplish this :)

Answer (score 0):

The default settings for navigation using metadata tags is to create a "friendly url" that one will be directed to when you click on the tag from the navigation bar. But because the page is not created yet, the site will show the "page does not exist" template.

To display pages that are associated to the term is something I am trying to figure out too, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any other way to do this, but from what I understand the links here are "Friendly URL's" and don't point to an actual page within the Wiki.

I'm still trying to understand the concept/ benefit of friendly URL's, but, what I have found is that on the Term Store Management Tool, if you click on a Term (assuming you have enabled navigation), you will see a tab called "Term-Driven pages". Then tick the checkbox for "Change target page for children of this term" and browse the page you would like users to be directed to when they click on the nav link.